# How to pass custom flags in a `bazel query` command?

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

I try to query deps with a custom flags. For example,

`bazel query --define=using_cuda=true "deps(@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:lib)"`

Bazel complained:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: --define=using_cuda=true
```

How could I pass a custom flag to `bazel query` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bazel query` doesn't support the `--define` flag because the command doesn't use it. Instead, use [`bazel cquery`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cquery.html) instead, which stands for "configurable query".